# Where to place a method that shares logic of two classes

Tags: c#, architecture

I have two classes, `BuildingHandler` and `TestHandler`.

`BuildingHandler` contains a method to `LoadBuildings` and `TestHandler` contains one to `LoadTests()`

Now I would like to create a function called `LoadBuildingTests`.

I'm unsure what handler to place this in as the functionality relates to both  Buildings and Tests.

I'm leaning towards having `LoadBuildingTests` in the `BuildingHandler`, then once IDs have been retrieved calling `TestHandler.LoadTests();`

Does this seem reasonable, or am I approaching it the wrong way? Should I be looking into interfaces, or another approach?

Comment: _Does this seem reasonable_ - it depend on context of your application.

Comment: thanks for comments, I could forsee the BuildingHandler becoming quite lengthy if I added other methods to it that are similar to LoadBuildingTests(). I suppose thats pointing to my answer.

Comment: Why would you want to combine both method into one? Is the logic the same? Why one method doing both things at once? What is the context of your application? Are they executed at once each time or one after another?

Comment: LoadBuildingTests will load/init the building, get the TestIDs needed and then call LoadTests. I think this steers me to having LoadBuildingTests in the BuildingHandler and then calling the TestHandler to load the tests

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd leave `LoadBuildingTests` inside `BuildingHandler` and pass in the `TestHandler` as an argument:

```
public class BuildingHandler
{
    public static void LoadBuildingTests(TestHandler testHandler)
    {
        if (testHandler == null) throw ....

        var building = LoadBuilding();
        var tests = testHandler.LoadTests(building.Id);
        //....
    }

    //..
}
```

Equally valid would be to implement the method in `TestHandler` and pass in the `BuildingHandler` as the argument but I have insufficient context to decide which is better. At first glance, I like the first option more.

Comment: this is perfect. Thanks InBetween.

Comment: @atoms Also consider, any time you are injecting a dependency, to use an interface `LoadBuildingTests(ITestHandler testHandler)`; that way you don't tie yourself down with a concrete implementation of `TestHandler`.

Comment: great advice, will implement the interface once/whilst refactoring. Thank you